# Change image of Facebook Send Button

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to change the image of the facebook send button? I want my own image with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have that level of customisation on a Social Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You can if you give your link/image an id, and then use jquery/javascript to call the Facebook send dialog when it's clicked.

```
$(function () {
    $("#LINK_ID").click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            display: ...,
            name: ...,
            link: ...,
            redirect_uri: ...,
        })
    };

    ...
})
```

Comment: This method works as intended - should really be the accepted answer